# push operation in a stack with scanf

Tags: c, struct, stack

I am trying to simulate a stack using a doubly linked list.
When I write the following code the output is what it is supposed to be.

```
    push_ch(12, "TNT");
    push_ch(13, "ABC");
    push_ch(14, "ESPN");
    display();

OUTPUT
    12 TNT
    13 ABC
    14 ESPN
```

However, I have a problem when the arguments are provided from the stdin.
An example input is:

```
3 --> number of operations
push c 12 TNT
push c 13 ABC
push c 14 ESPN
```

In the main function, I have written these to get the arguments.

```
scanf("%d", &i);
while(i){
    scanf("%s ", temp1);
    if(!strcmp(temp1, "push")){
        scanf("%c ", &j);
        if(j == 'c'){
            scanf("%d %s[^\n]", &k, temp2);
            push_ch(k, temp2);
            display();
        }
     }
i--;
}
```

Here `temp1`, and `temp2` are fixed size arrays. I have also called display function after each push operation to see what is happening. The output when the input is provided from  the stdin is this:

```
12 TNT
//stack after first push
12 ABC
13 ABC
//stack after second push
12 ESPN
13 ESPN
14 ESPN
//stack after third push
```

As you see, on the second push, the first element has changed. Similarly, on the third push, first two elements have been modified. There is no problem with their channel numbers. They are as what they should be somehow.

Here is the channel definition

```
typedef struct channel {
    struct channel * next;
    struct channel * back;
    int c_id;
    char * c_name;
    program * head_p;
    program * current_p;
} channel;
```

And this is the push_ch function I have written. Please ignore that it is not O(1).

```
void push_ch(int id, char *str){
    channel *temp;
    temp = head_c;
    if(temp == NULL){
        temp = malloc(sizeof(channel));
        temp->c_id = id;
        temp->c_name = str;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->back = NULL;
        temp->head_p = NULL;
        temp->current_p = NULL;
        head_c = temp;
    }
    else{
        while((temp->next) != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(channel));
        temp->next->c_id = id;
        temp->next->c_name = str;
        temp->next->next = NULL;
        temp->next->head_p = NULL;
        temp->next->current_p = NULL;
        temp->next->back = temp;
    }
}
```

To sum up, there is no problem when I call the push function by hand several times to add items to the stack. However, if the input is provided from stdin, the string value of all nodes changes to the that of last node. I'd be glad if someone could show me where the problem is.

Comment: Likely need to replicate string in `...c_name = str` --> `...c_name = strdup(str)`.

Comment: @chux Yes that solves it, thank you. I just malloc'd `c_name` and wrote `strcpy(...->c_name, str)` in the push function and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code needs to replicate `str` in `push_ch(int id, char *str)`

Example:

```
char *str_dup = strdup(str);
...
temp->c_name = str_dup;
...
temp->next->c_name = str_dup;
```

If `strdup()` unavailable, make your own

```
char *my_strdup(const char *s) {
  if (s) {
    size_t length = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *newptr = malloc(length);
    if (newptr) {
      return memcpy(newptr, s, length);
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Also use [@iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376902/2410359) answer to cope with user input.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, `scanf("%c ", &j);`, should be `scanf(" %c", &j);` because otherwise it will read the white space left by the previous `scanf()`, which did not consume the one that you explicitly left after the `"%s"` specifier.

That only applies to the `"%c"` specifier, the `"%s"` specifier will stop when it encounters a white space, and it expects a `" "` i.e. a space character, while in `" %c"`, any white space character as returned by `isspace()` will be consumed and then the input character you are trying to capture.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &i);`, `scanf("%s", temp1);` `scanf(" %c", &j);`, `scanf("%d %s", &k, temp2);`. If this is what you suggest, I am still having the same problem.

Comment: The code in the comment appears to be sending the correct data to `push_ch`. I wrote a printf(str) at the top of the push function to see what is coming.

Comment: Don't use `scanf()`, use `fgets()` and parse the string.